# Как хранить аккаунты соцсетей в Laravel?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

На моем сайте пользователи могут войти через соцсети (Facebook, Google, Twitter и т. д.).

Для этого я создал модель *Connection* и таблицу *connections* со структурой - *id*, *network_id*, user_id, *uid* (ID в соцсети). Кроме того, у меня есть модель *Network* и таблица *networks* для хранения списка соцсетей. Структура такая - *id*, *name*. С помощью relationshop я подключил Пользователя к Connection как «один ко многим».

Я сделал все правильно?

Comment: как минимум один из айдишников лишний

Answer (score 0):

В Connection протяни свзязь к Network.

Чтобы мог обращаться $user->connection->network->names (выдаст имена соцсетей  текущего пользователя).

+не забывай грузить это всё дело "жадной загрузкой", при ленивой будет очень много запросов, если ты например захочешь получить всех пользователей и все их соцсети.
Жадная используется так: например в контроллере

$users = User::all()->with("тут имена связей через запятую");